# How to retrieve data from database through anchor tag and display in list in html using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

anyone please help me to retrieve the db data and how to view it in html table.in the below code i was trying to fetch data from database using anchor tag. please tell me hoe should is write it in codeigniter.and i have to display that by clicking that on that anchor tag dynamically.

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('afc_view');
}

function search_course()
{
        $data['results'] = $this->afc_search->search_course();
        $this->load->view('afc_view', $data);
}
```

**model**

```
function search_course()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT course_name FROM courses");
    return $query->result();
}
```

**view**

```
                        <h3>Search</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Loc">
                        <div class="l">Location
                        </div>
                        <div id="loc">
                            <ul class="loct" >
                                <li class ="active">
                                    <a href="<? echo base_url('afcks/search_course');?>">Camp
                                    </a>

                                        <ul class="course">
                                            <li >

                                                <a title="excel" href="#">

                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <div id="top">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </div>
                <!--<div id="side">
                </div>-->
            </div>



    </div
```

Comment: Unclear information, please tell us more. What do you want?

Comment: if we click on anchor tag then it should dynamically fetch the data from database and display it in list under that link (anchor tag).and when we click on that link it goes to the function of controller then to write query it send to model and then it returns the data and then we send to view to display it dynamically .So i tried but i didn't get any output

Comment: Use Ajax calls on click to retrieve data

Comment: Have you knowledge how to use Ajax with in php?

Comment: yes i do ,we have to write it in script.

Comment: OK great write your script if you stuck let me know I will help you.

Comment: use query string in url `http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php` method or form post to pass the data from html to server

Comment: but have to do using anchor tag

Comment: Can anyone help me out of this.